# How to add tags to code snippets?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I tried very hard during the day to add  and  tags but could not do as expected.

Can someone help me to add the  tag and the  tag in this code snippet?

```
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), '<span class="meta-sep">,</span> ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:' , count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );
```

For example:

```
<th>Category:</th> <td>Kit baby</td>

echo '<th>SKU:</th>' . '<td>' . $product->get_sku() . '</td>';
```

[image]

**Please help me thanks.**

Comment: In Which page you want to display above code?

Comment: @PPL I am using the above code for a single product page

Comment: Means you want to display product sku on single product page.

Comment: If possible please share image so we can  exactly get idea.

Comment: @PPL I want to display "category" with <th> <td> tags like "sku", thanks           https://prnt.sc/jg2pjk

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Product Tags:

```
<?php
$current_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) {  
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Tags: </th>';  
    foreach ($current_tags as $tag) {
        $tag_title = $tag->name;
        $tag_link = get_term_link( $tag );
        echo '<td><a href="'.$tag_link.'">'.$tag_title.'</a></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
} ?>
```

Display Product Category:

```
<?php
$current_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) {  
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Category: </th>';  
    foreach ($current_tags as $tag) {
        $tag_title = $tag->name;
        $tag_link = get_term_link( $tag );
        echo '<td><a href="'.$tag_link.'">'.$tag_title.'</a></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
} ?>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: What  is the problem?

Comment: Where you have add this function?

Comment: Because with the use of above code, we can get product tags and category as per requirement.

Comment: can we move to chat section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170775/discussion-between-ppl-and-duc-phuli).